# Trying to derive a result on conditional probability

Tags: probability

We have $X_1,...$ indepdent random variables with common distribution $F$ and $N$ is a geometric random variable independent of $X_i$'s. Let $M = \max(X_1,...X_N)$. Im trying to convince myself that

$$ P( M \leq x \mid N > 1 ) = F(x) P(M \leq x ) $$

I understand that since $X_1$ is independent of all $X_i's$ and from $N$, when we can pull it out of the probability and we have

$$ P(X_1 \leq x) P( \max(X_2,....,X_N ) \leq x \mid N > 1 ) $$

And then we have 
$$ F(x)  P( \max( X_1,...,X_{N-1} \leq x \mid N > 1 ) $$

How does

$$ P( \max( X_1,...,X_{N-1} \leq x \mid N > 1 )  = P( M \leq x ) $$

??

Comment: Why not compute $P(M\leqslant x,N>1)$, $P(N>1)$ and $P(M\leqslant x)$ separately, and compare the results? For example, $$P(M\leqslant x,N>1)=\sum_{n\geqslant2}P(M\leqslant x,N=n)=\sum_{n\geqslant2}P(X_1\leqslant x,\ldots,X_n\leqslant x,N=n)$$ hence $$P(M\leqslant x,N>1)=\sum_{n\geqslant2}F(x)^np(1-p)^{n-1}=\cdots$$

Comment: i dont understand how this helps. How is the RHS of second expression equal to $P(M \leq x )$ . I dont see it. I understand if you use the law of total probability, but I want to understand the above without using law of total probability

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what you mean by "the RHS of second expression". Anyway, once you would have computed the probabilities I suggested, simply use $$P(M\leqslant x\mid N>1)=\frac{P(M\leqslant x,N>1)}{P(N>1)}$$ and conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, the conditional distribution of $N-1$ given $N > 1$ is also geometric.

$$P(N-1 = k \mid N > 1) = P(N = k+1)/P(N>1) = (1-p)^k p / (1 - p) = (1-p)^{k-1} p.$$

So $\max(X_1, \ldots, X_{N-1})$ given $N > 1$ has the same distribution as $M$.

Comment: I understand, but Im not convinced, since by your reasoning, then we would have also

$$ P(M \leq x ) = P ( M \leq x \mid N > 0 ) $$

Comment: @Neymar I am using geometric distributions that take values $1,2,\ldots$, so $N>0$ always holds.